# Что такое "client-specific data" в условиях лицензии?

Tags: лицензирование

Интересует приобретение лицензии библиотеки highcharts.

И там есть лицензия для одного разработчика и одного домена.
Но еще написано про какую то client-specific data.

> The Single Website license applies to one developer on a selected
>   domain without the use of client-specific data.

https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts

Вот интересует какую лицензию следует выбрать, нам нужна лицензия для сайта на один домен. График выполняется на странице, данные приходят через ajax с сервера и потом строится график.
У нас компания, высокая посещаемость, 1 домен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

там в разделе https://shop.highsoft.com/faq

> A project is considered a web application if it provides client
>   specific data or charges for its use. **Client specific data is data**
>   **that is available for a client either by a login or a specific URL. An**
>   **example of this would be a weather service where your users can create**
>   **an account and store their location for later use**. On the other hand,
>   if your weather service only serves weather data by location and your
>   users need to search for their nearest town, the data is available for
>   all users, and it is not considered client specific.

т.е. это данные, которые заточены под конкретного клиента через эккаунт/секретную (фактически) ссылку, если же любой пользователь может получать любые данные - то это не client-specific